# Unable to open Runner.xcworkspace

Tags: flutter

Getting an error while opening Runner.xcworkspace 
Error => The document “Runner.xcworkspace” could not be opened. The file doesn’t exist.

https://ibb.co/ncmXWcy

https://ibb.co/gjt8xgb
While opening Xcode